# Pass authentication from IIS to JBoss

Tags: iis, authentication, jboss

I am using AJP to redirect users from IIS 8 to a JBOSS (EAP 6) site and relay the authentication details (windows integrated authentication).

On JBOSS 5 I could use

```
<connector name="ajp" protocol="AJP/1.3" scheme="http" socket-binding="ajp" enabled="true" tomcatAuthentication="false"  />
```

However  `tomcatAuthentication="false"` is no longer supported on JBOSS 6:

What is the new way to do this. I found https://access.redhat.com/solutions/238033 but I am having difficulties with gaining access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like adding this to the JBOSS config is the correct way as of v6.1

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="org.apache.coyote.ajp.DEFAULT_TOMCAT_AUTHENTICATION" value="false"/>
</system-properties
```